# Fetching only 9 digit using python regex

Tags: python, regex

When i try to fetch the only 9 digit value (4901773349) in addition to that i get 803000000 too by

```
ref3=re.findall(r'(\d{9})',fin.read())`
```

the string to find is 116R00003     8030000000000000    4901773349

Comment: 4901773349 are 10 digits, use word boundaries `\b\d{10}\b` see https://regex101.com/r/4YkeKQ/1

Comment: Well, that is an other match of your regular expression. You will have to limit it in some way.

Comment: would `fin.split()[-1]` not suffice?

Comment: Your regex works as intended. You need to add "this should be the beginning or end of the word" - `\b`. There are online editors to help with regexes - I recommend you use them, they provide a list of regex symbols and explanations as well.

Comment: Thank you The fourth bird. Its done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly thers 10 digits in your regex.

Secondly try this, because you have to think about spaces while checking this regex.

`\b\d{10}\b`

Comment: Why all these capture groups? Have look at https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: Sure, You are right. I edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is always in this format, yo can modify your regexp like so:

```
re.findall(r'(\b\d{10})$', fin.read())
```

This will match the last 10 digits on the line, but only if it's preceded by a word boundary (\b).

Comment: Notice that it fill capture only last word in string. If u want to find intermediate words change `$` for word boundary `\b`

Comment: Noticed. This captures what he wanted to capture in the input he provided.